# SharePoint 2010 Workflow question using Designer

Tags: workflow, designer-workflow

I need to create a workflow for a custom list (having two columns Title and Hyperlink). When an item is created in that list the workflow should ceate a corresponding item in a discussion list with the same Title and the Hyperlink field in the first list should be updated with the URL of the discussion item.

Answer (score 1):

The Create List Item workflow action, under List Actions, returns the ID of the created item. You can store this in a workflow variable.

[image]

Then set the Hyperlink field to a concat string with the fix part like

`http://myserver/sites/a/lists/mylist/DispForm.aspx?ID=` plus the variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can be little more clear about your question. As far as I understood... You need to create an item in discussion board, when item is created in the custom list. For implementing it you can use the action 'Create List Item' in SharePoint Designer workflow which creates list item in another list.

Comment: yes, i did this, after creating item in another list i need to get the url of that particular list item to be updated in the currentllist item feild hyperlink.

Comment: my custom list name lets consider as Issue which contains columns (Title and Hyperlink),i have given Title name and saved it,now i need  a discussion board item to be created using this title in TeamDiscussions,up to this i have completed,Now my requirement is i need this Discussion board item url,to be updated in my Issue list Hyperlink Feild.

Comment: You can do this using action 'Update List Item'. In that select 'Current Item' then click Add button where you will be asked for field and value. Select the field in current item and for value you can lookup to discussion board list(Press function button near value textbox).
Now in Datasource select 'Team Discussion', In field from source select URL path. Below you can find field and value which is used to link your list and discussion list. You should mention a column which is common to both the lists. Try it...